# Bash script to open URLs in Firefox doesn't work

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, firefox, terminal

I wrote the following bash script to read in a text file of URLs and open them as new tabs in Firefox. However, the script only opens the first URL from the list. I have to quit Firefox before the script opens the second URL. I want the script to open the URLs as new tabs in the same session.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --new-tab "$line"

done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Bash only opened the first URL if Firefox was not already running, but it opened all URLs as new tabs if Firefox was already running. The script works if you launch Firefox first.